# How to remove template from DOM from different template

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

this seems to be very easy, but i couldnt find a method in the blaze docs that helped me. 
I have two templates, for simplicity lets call them `templateOne` and `templateTwo`. In `templateTwo` i have a click function:

```
Template.templateTwo.events({
    'click button'(){
        Blaze.remove(Template.templateOne);
    }
});
```

Which gives me the error `Uncaught Error: Expected DOM element or View`
I also tried :

```
Template.templateOne.instance().view; (dont knowif this exist's)
Template.templateOne.view; (seems like it doesnt exist)
```

However when logging `Template.templateOne`it returns a Blaze.Template. but i couldnt find a view. So how is it possible for my to remove this template or at least get the view of the template?